# PHP How to list all total earning of day of selected month

Tags: php, database, date

How to display all date of the month and total earning of each day. I think my monthlyreport.php wrong badly. I no idea how to do it. Please help me to solve the problem. This is important for me. Thank you for your help.

My output something like this:

```
Month November
No      Date       Total earning
1       1/11/2014  100    
2       2/11/2014  200
3       3/11/2014  400
```

My database something like this:

```
//tblvisit
Id  VisitDate   PatientId   PatientName DoctorName  Symptom Test     Diagnosis  TotalPrice
1   2014-11-05  123         John        mr wong     flu     checking panadol    31
```

My `monthlyreport.php`:

```
<tr>
  <td>No</td>
  <td>Date</td>            
  <td>Total Earned</td>
</tr>
<?php
  for($i=0;$i<mysql_num_rows($SearchResult); $i++)
  {
    $visitRec = mysql_fetch_array($SearchResult);
    echo "<tr> ";
    echo "<td>".($i+1)."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$visitRec['VisitDate']."</td>";

    $total = 0;                 
    $id = $visitRec['Id'];
    $date = $_POST['txtSMonth'];
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblvisit WHERE VisitDate ='$date'") or die(mysql_error());
    while($row= mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
    {
      $total += $row['TotalPrice'];
    }                                                      
    echo "<td>".$total."</td>";                             
    echo "</tr>";
  }?>
```

Comment: what you tried on sql will you post that too. don't use mysql_ function instead of this use PDO http://php.net/pdo And don't use $_POST global array directly read example1 here http://in1.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Comment: @gvgvgvijayan It's easy to say "use PDO" for someone familiar with it. But IMO mysqli is a much better transition for someone using mysql.

Comment: @EternalHour No one is familiar at the start. Continuous learning only makes us better one. Lets I say why I insisted PDO over mysqli 1. Migration is easy since same function for all 12 drivers only connection values vary. 2. API is complete oop so in team project there is no confusion either others write procedural or oop 3. Prepared statements on Client (php) side is possible and db those don't support also emulate it. Also I didn't force him must use PDO. I just give a suggestion by seeing his code. And always welcome to give suggestion on my comment & post. Thanks pal!!!

Comment: 4.Mysqli doesn't support named parameter.

Comment: I see your points, but what I'm saying is that the learning curve from mysql to mysqli is much less. Someone can move from mysql to mysqli API and convert to OOP and once familiar, then transition to PDO is much less painful.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following query as inner query :

```
    SELECT sum(TotalPrice) FROM tblvisit WHERE VisitDate ='$date' group by VisitDate
```

Hope it will work for you.